# Xcode Plugin - get access to the main textView of the opened file

Tags: xcode, macos

I want to build an Xcode plugin that marks some text in the opened file (mainly .h and .m files).

I am trying to get reference to the main textView,

Any direction ?

Comment: Isn't this a little...broad?

Comment: Why ? This is a very specific task. get the main active text view in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do have the plugin itself running and only need the main editor

```
+ (id)currentEditor {
    NSWindowController *currentWindowController = [[NSApp keyWindow] windowController];
    if ([currentWindowController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"IDEWorkspaceWindowController")]) {
        id workspaceController = (IDEWorkspaceWindowController *)currentWindowController;
        id editorArea = [workspaceController editorArea];
        id editorContext = [editorArea lastActiveEditorContext];
        return [editorContext editor];
    }
    return nil;
}

+ (NSTextView *)currentSourceCodeTextView {
    if ([[self currentEditor] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"IDESourceCodeEditor")]) {
        id editor = [XCFXcodeFormatter currentEditor];
        return [editor textView];
    }

    if ([[self currentEditor] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"IDESourceCodeComparisonEditor")]) {
        id editor = [XCFXcodeFormatter currentEditor];
        return [editor keyTextView];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: you could go and replace the IDs with real interface definitions when you are using the xcode headers (e.g. gotten via dumping)

Comment: Works great, for any one who wonder this comes from here https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode/blob/master/Classes/XCFXcodeFormatter.m

Comment: oh yes, sorry my bad. I contribute to & forked that repo. sorry